# Howto use repo tool to mirror a project composed of several git repositories

Tags: git, repository, repo

I want to make a fork of a project composed of several .git repos, pushing all of them to different (local) repositories, but maintaining exactly the same set of branches and tags for each individual git repo.

This project is initially downloaded using the "repo" tool. There is a manifest.xml file describing the location of each single .git repository, downloaded with repo init, and then repo sync clones all the git repos.

I will use bitbucket.com in this example, but don't focus the attention on bitbucket, is just an example.

This are the steps I am doing right now:

1. Create an empty manifest.git repository in bitbucket. Then:

   ```bash
   cd existing-manifest.git
   git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.com/project/manifest.git
   git push -u origin --all
   git push origin --tags
   ```
2. Create the set of git repos manually inside bitbucket. Then:

   ```bash
   #! /bin/sh
   for LINE in $(repo forall -c 'echo ${REPO_PROJECT}":"${REPO_PATH}')
   do
       REPO_PROJECT=$(echo $LINE | cut -f 1 -d ":")
       REPO_PATH=$(echo $LINE | cut -f 2 -d ":")
       pushd $REPO_PATH
       git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.com/project/${REPO_PROJECT}.git
       git push -u origin --all
       git push origin --tags
       popd
   done
   ```

After that, edit the manifest.xml manually to change the default remote of each project and commit the new manifest.xml in my custom repo.

This is a very manual process, not very friendly. So my questions are:

1. Can this process be improved in some way?
2. Is possible just using the "repo" tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd step can be improved. `repo forall` is enough and you don't need to wrap it with `for`.

```
repo forall -p -c 'git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.com/project/${REPO_PROJECT}.git \
                   && git push -u origin --all --tags'
```

The manifest.xml can have these tags and attributes,

```
<remote fetch="ssh://git@bitbucket.com/project" name="origin" />
<default remote="origin" revision="foo" />
<project name=bar path=bar />
```

which define a default remote `origin`, so that you don't need to specify the remote for every project unless one or more of them are hosted in other places. For the project `bar`, its default remote will be `origin ssh://git@bitbucket.com/project/bar` for both fetch and push.

Comment: Your answer was really helpfull. Thanks a lot!! :-)